# MockRestServiceServer for AsyncRestTemplate

Tags: spring, testing, asynchronous, resttemplate

Spring 4 introduced AsyncRestTemplate, but I see no tool like MockRestServiceServer for this template. Is there any way to create tests for AsyncRestTemplate with mock server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Spring 4.1 will add this support: https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/28/spring-framework-4-1-spring-mvc-improvements